# Reviving an old but very useful Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I've been using this Wordpress plugin for many years https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-post-navigation/

It had over 20,000 active installations and is certainly most useful for navigating between posts in the backend by simply clicking Next / Previous.

Gutenberg and Wordpress 5 unfortunately broke it and the developer of the plugin seems to be MIA.

My knowledge of writing or even trying to fix plugins is sketchy to say the last. I did some digging today using Developer Tools and I found that my favourite little post navigation buttons are there but forcefully hidden by Wordpress. Here's a screenshot of how I can make them re-appear but I'm a bit stumped how to make a change like this permanent or better yet try to make the plugin force it's way back into Wordpress 5 and Gutenberg.

I did make a feature request on Gutenberg which was promptly closed, seems they are not too interested in pleasing any advanced or long time users of wordpress. Surely such a navigation system cannot be rocket science.
[image: screengrab]

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: The plugin you mentioned is still working fine. In the posts editor in the right sidebar you should have the post navigation option. Click on settings if sidebar is not visible by default.

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan I have this plugin on many sites all with different themes and not one of them will show it in the sidebar. The option is definitely turned on for the sidebar but not showing at all, even switched to default wordpress themes like twenty ten, twenty eleven etc etc, just does not show.

Comment: @cabrerahector sorry my question is how to make those buttons next/prev re-appear at the top as in my screengrab

Comment: @Ehsan just created a brand new clean install of WP 5.1.1 no other plugins except for Admin Post Navigation and the default theme and still nothing displays.

Comment: @MitchellK I tested it yesterday on localhost and it showed up fine. Now on live site it doesn't show up. I will test it later to see if i can find the solution...

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan really appreciate it, it's honestly become one of my most useful plugins and having to update over 200 posts is now a nightmare